# C#: normal and static void with same name

Tags: c#, class, static, instance, void

I want to create a "log" class. There will be a global logger for the main things. but when the network part want log something to its own logger, it should be able to. My idea: a static logger instance in the logger class and a static void with the same name to log something. example:

```
Logger.log("ahaha");
```

will log something to the main logger and

```
new logger().log("kdsjfklsjd");
```

will log to a special logger. Here the code for my class:

```
public class Logger
{
    public static Logger GlobalLogger = new Logger();

    public Logger()
    {
    }

    public void log(string message)
    {
    }

    public static void log(string message)
    {
        Logger.GlobalLogger.log(message);
    }
}
```

I want tell the code that when i want to Logger.GlobalLogger.log(message) it should use the nonstatic void (with the same name)

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: your solution is good so what you want exactly?

Comment: if both have same parameters then yeah you need singleton

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it quite like that. You'll get the compiler error:

> Type 'Logger' already defines a member called 'Log' with the same parameter types

You have two main options to resolve this:

1. Define static methods with different parameters:

   ```
   public class Logger
   {
       public void Log(string message) { ... }

       public static void Log(string message, int level) { ... }
   }
   ```
2. Follow a ['singleton'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) pattern:

   ```
   public class Logger
   {
       public void Log(string message) { ... }

       private static Logger globalLogger;
       public static Logger GlobalLogger 
       {
           get
           {
               if (globalLogger == null)
               {
                   globalLogger = new Logger();
               }

               return globalLogger;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: That is not what i wanted to get! I think here is the same problem as in my code. I want to call the void log from an instance of Logger and directly without an instance of it with the static void.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this compiler error is to add an interface:

```
public interface ILogger {
    void Log(string message);
}

public class Logger : ILogger {
    public static readonly ILogger GlobalLogger = new Logger();

    // explicit implementation allows the static and instance Log() to coexist peacefully
    void ILogger.Log(string message) { /* log */ }

    public static void Log(string message) { GlobalLogger.Log(message); }
}
```

One nice benefit of this pattern is that it is easy to provide many implementations of the ILogger interface. For example, you might even consider making the `Logger` class static (doesn't implement `ILogger`) and making a separate `GlobalLogger` class:

```
public static class Logger {
    public static readonly ILogger Global = new GlobalLogger();

    public static void Log(string message) { Global.Log(message); }
}

public class GlobalLogger : ILogger {
    void Log(message) { /* log */ }
}
```

Comment: Looks goot, i will try it!

Comment: is this right?

void ILogger.Log(string message){Console.WriteLine("[INFO] " + message); }

after calling Logger.log("da shit"); it does nothing!

Comment: @danbru1211: That looks fine. Did you set a breakpoint inside your Log() method to see if it's getting called? Console.WriteLine() may be working but not going where you expect.